# Convertir el valor de una cadena al nombre de una funcion

Tags: string, perl, funcion

Requiero llamar a una función en **Perl** a través de la formación de una cadena la cual será creada de acuerdo al rango de fechas elegidas por el usuario.

```perl
$cadena= "obtener_prom=(\%HoH, '2023-01-01','2023-01-02','2023-01-03',)";
```

Como se puede observar estoy creando bien la cadena para llamar a la función **obtener_prom**, sin embargo no se ejecuta la llamada a la función.

El resultado esperado es que se ejecute la función.

Answer (score 2):

Creo que sobra el signo "=" después de "obtener_prom". Y una vez conformada la cadena, debes evaluarla con eval(), para que se ejecute.

Ejemplo:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use v5.24;

my $cadena= "obtener_prom('2023-01-01','2023-01-02','2023-01-03',)";

say eval $cadena;

sub obtener_prom {
    my @fechas = @_;

    return join "|", @fechas;
}
```

Salida:

```
2023-01-01|2023-01-02|2023-01-03
```

Comment: Gracias Enormes Joaquín Ferrero. Respetos.

Comment: @XochitlMora, la forma de mostrar agradecimiento es [votar a favor](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) de la respuesta, y si lograste con ella resolver tu problema, también [aceptarla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) para que en el futuro otros sepan que esta es la que te ayudó a resolver. Más información en [que hacer cuando me contestan](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Que tal Joaquín, sigo tus consejos pero al ejecutarse la función returm envia:

Comment: Si has probado el ejemplo que te he dado, y funciona, pues entonces el problema está en que no sabemos lo que hace la función obtener_prom(), así que no podemos ayudarte. Debes probar a llamar a la función de forma directa, para ver si funciona como esperas. Luego veremos porqué no funciona con el eval().

Comment: Enormes gracias Joaquín, una de las razones que pueden estar provocando es que estoy utilizando una versión muy anterior de perl:  perl 5 versión 16 subversión 3 y Tú estas usando la versión use v5.24;. Pero no debería, o si?

Comment: El "use v5.24;" es sólo para poder usar la función "say", que está disponible desde Perl v5.10. Te vale con cambiar "use v5.24;" por "use v5.16.3;".

Comment: Que tal Joaquín, genero el %HoH a través de una consulta  a una PSQL DB :  
$HoH{$date}{$hm}=$valor
Al terminar de generarse el $HoH lo imprimo y el resultado es:
$VAR1={
‘2023-01-01’=>{’00:00’=>’352.24’, ’00:02’=>’352.14’, ’00:07’=>’398.01’,…, ’23:56’=>’344.00’,’23:56=>’399.00’},’2023-01-02’=>{’00:00’=>’352.24’, ’00:02’=>’401.00’, ’00:03’=>’401.00’,…, ’23:56’=>’403.99’,’23:57’=>’411.00’, ’23:58’=>’403.11’}}
Agradeceré enormemente tu apoyo para validar si la estructura del HOH es correcta.

Comment: Lo siento, pero no sé si esa estructura es la esperada por la función obtener_prom(), Eso lo deberías saber si tienes acceso al código fuente de la función o si tienes algún ejemplo del formato de las entradas que ella espera.